# /usr/local/include unintendedly added to my compile commands results in build failing

Tags: macos, cmake, clang, homebrew, libpng

## Background

I'm compiling, on a machine which runs macOS 10.15, a project which ships an old version of libpng (1.6.17) as a submodule. The corresponding code is available at https://github.com/glennrp/libpng. I also have libpng 1.6.37 installed by Homebrew.

Until not so long ago, I was able to compile libpng 1.6.17 using CMake without trouble. Since very recently (but the exact date is unknown to me), build fails with errors like:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngwutil.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc  -I/usr/local/include -I. -I../ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngwutil.o -MF CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngwutil.o.d -o CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngwutil.o   -c ../pngwutil.c
../pngwutil.c:2413:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PNG_WEIGHT_SHIFT'
                   PNG_WEIGHT_SHIFT;
                   ^
```

I ran a few checks against a copy of my project I had which still compiled correctly because CMake wasn't re-running itself on it. The only difference between the two cases is a `-I/usr/local/include` flag added to compiler calls (I added some markup to help see the difference):

- suceeds:

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -Dpng16_EXPORTS -Iext_build/libpng -I../../ext/libpng -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fPIC   -fno-stack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-math-errno -ffp-contract=fast -march=native -MD -MT ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o -MF ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o.d -o ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o   -c ../../ext/libpng/pngrio.c
                                                                                           <---------------------------------->
  ```
- fails:

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -Dpng16_EXPORTS -I/usr/local/include -Iext_build/libpng -I../../ext/libpng -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fPIC   -fno-stack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-math-errno -ffp-contract=fast -march=native -MD -MT ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o -MF ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o.d -o ext_build/libpng/CMakeFiles/png16.dir/pngrio.o   -c ../../ext/libpng/pngrio.c
                                                                                           <------------------------------------------------------->
  ```

I re-ran CMake on the copy of the project which was working and I got the same error, which pointed me to a system-related problem. I then checked out directly the libpng sources and got the same error.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Clone the libpng repo and check out v1.6.17

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/glennrp/libpng.git
   cd libpng
   git checkout v1.6.17
   ```
2. Build libpng

   ```
   cmake . -B build && cmake --build build
   ```

## Question

*What did add this `-I/usr/local/include` flag to my compiler calls?*

## Bonus question (maybe more interesting)

Now, it gets funny. If you checkout a more recent libpng (I tried with 1.6.21, 1.6.25, 1.6.28, 1.6.33 and 1.6.37), the problem goes away, although the flag is still here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc  -I/usr/local/include -I. -I../ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngrio.o -MF CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngrio.o.d -o CMakeFiles/png16_static.dir/pngrio.o   -c ../pngrio.c
```

This means that I could update my submodule use one of these releases and my problem would go away.

However, if I'm not not mistaken, `-I` flags are resolved from left to right: I therefore suspect that my Homebrew headers are used instead of the source ones. If I'm right, then this doesn't guarantee that a Homebrew upgrade of libpng won't break the build again: it just shows that libpng's API has been stable since v1.6.21 and that I can use my Homebrew headers with the source I'm trying to compile. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of it. It turned out that libpng's zlib dependency was the one giving me trouble (indirectly).

## What happened

MacOS ships zlib and it is usually known to developers who therefore don't feel the need to install a 3rd party zlib. However, CMake's `find_package` doesn't know about this preference and will pick up a zlib implementation found in `/usr/local`, for instance if it is installed by Homewbrew. For some reason, a zlib was installed by 3rd party software at this location on my system—not a Homebrew package, which made the detection more difficult, and it was detected by `find_package`.

The corresponding include directory is `/usr/local/include`. libpng's CMake code is such that this directory is then added to the list of include directories, which leads to the header conflicts mentioned in the question. I understood what was happening by going through `CMakeCache.txt` (searching for `/usr/local/include`), so the main lesson is: *don't forget to check your CMake cache in such situations*.

## How to solve the problem

**The lazy way**. Remove the undesired lib files. I ran `brew doctor` and removed the files which were not supposed to be here. This, however, might have undesired consequences if the specific zlib version sitting in `/usr/local` is actually required by some piece of software.

**The dirty CMake way**. Modify the top-level CMake code to hint [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) about where it should pick zlib. Either hard-code the hint using the `PATHS` argument or set it using the `ZLIB_ROOT` argument (you might have to define policies for that).

I'm sure there is a better way to handle this by ["doing CMake right"](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) in libpng and forcing library search in system paths, but my CMake skills are not good enough to say what should be done exactly. And anyway, it's a bit off-topic with respect to the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. answer to question: the system include path is added by compiler/preprocessor ([this page](https://langui.sh/2015/07/24/osx-clang-include-lib-search-paths/) will explain more datails)
2. the order of included in CMake project may be changed (not sure how much), CMake allows prepend includes in the list; try compare CMake build scripts between releases. I believe there will be mentioned change.

Comment: Actually no: the CMake build scripts haven't changed, and that's what confuses me. I built the library successfully on other machines with apparently similar configuration (I also checked compiler calls to be sure) and didn't run into this error, so there must be something else setting these flags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sometimes cmake will pick up a variety of libs and include dirs and freely mix and match.  If you need to keep multiple versions up, you should use the cmake command to pass the correct packages.